# How to use "no commas" and "css custom properities" in a rgba value while using SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, css-variables, custom-properties

I"m trying to use CSS custom properties in a rgba value. I am able to get the desired result in pure css, but when I test this out in codepen.io or my IDE that are both using scss, I am getting an error of: `` overloaded function `rgba` given wrong number of arguments `` . How can I incorporate this in  SCSS

Here is a codepen that shows the error: https://codepen.io/tmocodes/pen/xxVdMEq?editors=1100
The below snippet works because it is not using SCSS.

```css
:root {
  --color-primary: 29 4 247;
  --lighten: 10%;
}

#element {
  background-color: rgba(var(--color-primary) / var(--lighten));
  color: rgb(var(--color-primary));
}
```

```html
<h1 id="element">Using CSS Custom Properities with opacity</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To incorporate modern comma-free CSS color syntax with SCSS, I've used this workaround.

The reason this doesn't work is that it conflicts with the Sass rgb/rgba function. You can uppercase one or more letters to make Sass ignore it (being case sensitive). [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/tannerdolby/pen/PoNJRPy).

```
$color-primary: 29 4 247;
$color-secondary: 247 4 4;
$lighten: 10%;

#element {
  background-color: Rgba($color-primary / $lighten);
  color: Rgb($color-primary);
}

#element-2 {
  background-color: Rgba($color-secondary / $lighten);
  color: Rgb($color-secondary);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SCSS preprocessor has to computed the vales before it can be assigned to the css variables.
Following approach might give you hint to approach the solution you are looking for.

`rgba` require 4 parameters

`rgb` require 3 parameters.

```
$blue: rgb(29, 4, 247);
$red: rgb(29, 4, 247);
$lighten: 10%;
:root {
  --color-primary: #{blue};
  --color-secondary: #{red};
  --lighten: #{lighten};
}
        
#element {
  background-color: lighten($blue, $lighten);
  color: $blue;
}

#element-2 {
  background-color: lighten($red, $lighten);
  color: $red;
}
```

I created the following [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hzaidi/pen/rNOBREy), that gives the idea of how to combine scss with css variables.